# How to write select query searching 3 tables in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find PolicyNumber from Table 1 which has at least 1 member associated.

1. Table 1:

   - Column 1: PolicyNumber
   - Column 2: UniqueNumber
2. Table 2:

   - Column 1: UniqueNumber[Same as Table1]
   - Column 2: MemberNumber
3. Table 3:

   - Column 1: MemberNumber
   - Column 2: MemberType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t1.UniqueNumberToPolicy, t3.MemberType, count(*) from 
Table1 t1, Table2 t2, Table3 t3
where t1.UniqueNumberToPolicy = t2.UniqueNumberToPolicy
and t2.MemberNumber = t3.MemberNumber
group by t1.UniqueNumberToPolicy, t2.MemberType
having count(*) > 0
```

Comment: Thank You. Just 1 change. Group by at the end its T3.membertype.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could include some explanation in your answer.